# Windows follows symlinks forever on samba share

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I have a network share that is accessed via Samba from Windows. In one of my network share folders, there is a symlink that points to the current directory. For example,

> /opt/myapp/mydir
>
> symlink mydir -> /opt/myapp/mydir

While the symlink is nonsensical, I am curious why in Windows Explorer, it seems to allow me to essentially navigate until I reach about 45 subdirectories and then there is nowhere to go but `/opt/myapp/mydir`, only symlink mydir is nowhere to be found at about the 45th depth. In essence the path becomes something like `\\nfs_server\share\myapp\mydir\mydir\mydir\..\mydir\mydir\mydir\mydir` etc. In `/etc/smb.conf`, I have `follow symlinks = yes`, `wide links = ye`s, and `unix extensions = no`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, Windows has a MAX_PATH length for file paths, about 260 characters.  45 subdirectories creates a path length that's larger than 260.  After that, I don't know how Windows behaves with Samba.